# Pre Spatializer Effect - Unity and Google VR Audio

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am using GVR Audio within unity to provide HRTF's for my audio sources, my project involves modelling the acoustics of the virtual environment which needs to happen before the HRTF filters.

On a default unity audio source there is an option to spatialise post effects, meaning I can insert my own effect there. However on the GVR Audio source there is no such option, what is the recomended way to spatialize post effects with GVR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GvrAudioSource uses Unity's [AudioSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) under the hood. This means, it is possible to apply pre-spatialization processing using the [OnAudioFilterRead](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html) method - as you'd normally write for audio sources in your script.

Alternatively, for other audio effect components that would require the *spatializePostEffects* option, you could simply enable the option through the script by adding the corresponding line below to Awake() function in GvrAudioSource.cs:

```
void Awake () {
  ...
  audioSource.spatialBlend = 1.0f;
  audioSource.spatializePostEffects = true;  // Add this line.
  OnValidate();
  ...
}
```

Please also note that, this unfortunately does not currently allow you to add Unity's stock AudioEffect components (e.g. [AudioLowPassFilter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioLowPassFilter.html)) in the Editor, as it'd complain about the lack of an AudioSource component in that game object. This is, however, only a UI limitation, i.e., adding a component with such restrictions in run time should still work as expected.

Hope this answers your question.

Cheers

Comment: Perfect thanks :) I assumed it would be something like this, but wanted some confirmation!